# How to prevent nautilus from launching in Xubuntu?

Tags: nautilus, xubuntu

I installed both Gnome/Unity and Xfce on my desktop, and I use Xfce (Xubuntu) as default when I log in. But every time I log in, nautilus launches by opening a folder and changing my wallpaper. The weird thing is that it's not even in "start-up applications". 
How to prevent nautilus from launching in Xubuntu?
So far, I'm just doing killall nautilus every time I log in.

Comment: Have you by any chnave activated Launch Gnome services at startup?.

Comment: No, it's not checked

Comment: Did kolis's answer help?

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove xfce cache:

```
$ rm ~/.cache/sessions/*
```